# Does a "typical" unitary matrix have an entry of magnitude 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory

I guess that a "typical" unitary matrix (or "almost every" unitary matrix) in $d \geq 2$ dimensions does not have an entry with magnitude 1. I would like to make this statement more precise and see a proof for it. My attempt to make this precise goes as follows.

Let $d \geq 2$, let $U(d)$ be the group of unitary matrices on $\mathbb{C}^d$, equipped with the Haar measure (of any non-zero normalization). Define the function $f: U(d) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $U \mapsto \Vert U \Vert_{\text{max}}$, where $\Vert U \Vert_{\text{max}} = \max_{i,j} \vert u_{ij} \vert$ is the maximum over the magnitude of the entries of the matrix $U$. Then the above statement would be: The preimage $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ has measure 0 in $U(d)$.

**vague question:** Is this an appropriate formulation of the statement that a typical unitary matrix does not have an entry of magnitude 1?

**Question 1:** Is the above statement true? If so, how is it proved?

**Question 2:** How can I state and prove that for $d \geq 3$, a typical $d$-dimensional unitary has the property that only one entry achives $\Vert U \Vert_{\text{max}} = \max_{i,j} \vert u_{ij} \vert$

Comment: I think somewhere you had better say $d\ge2$, since what you're asking seems to be false for $d=1$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: For $d \geqslant 2$, the set $U_{ij}(d) = \{ A \in U(d) : \lvert a_{ij}\rvert = 1\}$ is isomorphic to $S^1\times U(d-1)$. So it has smaller dimension than $U(d)$.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but aren't all entries of a diagonal unitary matrix of magnitude 1?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: Yes, but the diagonal matrices have zero measure in $U(d)$.

Answer (score 0):

For Questions 1:

A matrix $U$ is in $\mathcal{U}_n\Leftrightarrow$ the rows (and columns) form an orthonormal basis. Then if there is a 1 somewhere (say first row, first column) then the rest of the corresponding column and rows are 0's. Thus we get the set of all such matrices is a copy of $\mathcal{U}_{n-1}$, so to show $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is measure zero you have to note that it is the union of a finite number of lower dimensional submanifolds.